# At what point (runtime) does a broken reference raise an exception?

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am using a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in my application which will allows me to add a feature to convert a Word document to PDF. This feature will only ever be used by a few end users and these users will all have MS Office.

What happens when the application is started on a workstation which does not have Office? Will the app fail immediately or only when the Interop methods are called?

Comment: You should look into the "no PIA" feature we added to C# 4. It is little-known, but it was specifically designed to address this scenario with Office. It lets you ship code that uses the Office PIAs without actually requiring that the PIAs be present, and thereby mitigates some of the issues mentioned in Damien's answer.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness of information: another option is to use late-binding (PInvoke) so that the PIAs aren't used at all, not even embedded in the code.

Answer (score 2):

It should fail at the point at which it needs to load type information from the interop library. This will usually be at the point at which it's compiling any function that *calls* an interop method. Assuming you've not leaked any of it's types through any of your own method arguments, interfaces, base classes, etc.

This usually means that you want to write things like:

```
if(OfficeAvailable)
{
   DoOfficeWork();
}
else
{
   Fallback();
}
```

Rather than:

```
if(OfficeAvailable)
{
    var app = new Outlook.Application();
    app.DoSomething();
}
else
{
    //Do other things
}
```

I.e. push the office interactions down into dedicated methods that you don't even attempt to *call* if you're not working with office, rather than trying to detect and conditionally work with office inline in a single function.